# how to understand this new way to solve matrix under basis change?

Tags: linear-algebra, linear-transformations

I just found this exercise using a new shortcut to solve matrix under new basis given the old matrix, please enlighten me why this shortcut works:

**The Exercise**: relative to the standard unit vectors $e_1$, $e_2$, a linear map $A:\mathbb{R}^2 \to \mathbb{R}^2$ is described by the matrix $ A=\begin{pmatrix}
1 & 0 \\
0 & -1 \\
\end{pmatrix}$. Find the representing matrix $A'$ for this linear map relative to the basis $v'_1 = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \\ -\frac{1}{\sqrt2} \\ \end{pmatrix}$, $v'_2 = \begin{pmatrix} \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \\ \frac{1}{\sqrt2} \\ \end{pmatrix}$

Instead of traditional $A'=PAP^{-1}$ way, **the answer give a new shortcut**:
compute the images of the basis vectors and express them in $v'_i$ then the coefficients give the columns of $A'$.

$$Av'_1 = 0v'_1 + 1v'_2 , \ \ Av'_1 = 1v'_1 + 0v'_2$$

so $ A' = \begin{pmatrix}
0 & 1 \\
1 & 0 \\
\end{pmatrix}$

note1: I feel this shortcut only work when one of the basis is standard unit vectors.

note2: the book is using $[A]^e_e$ multiply $[v'_i]_e$, the result is $[Av'_i]_e$ in space **2** of the digram below, my confusion is why expressing them using $[v'_i]_e$ will give the matrix $[A']^{v'}_{v'}$ which should be get by expressing $[A'v'_i]_{v'}$ using $[v'_i]_{v'}$ that relating space 3, 4 of the digram.

$\require{AMScd}$
\begin{CD}
1\  \mathbb{R}^2 \text{ using basis } e @>A>>2\ \mathbb{R}^2 \text{ using basis } e\\
@V P=[I]^e_{v'} VV  @VV P V\\
3\ \mathbb{R}^2 \text{ using basis } v' @>>A'>4\ \mathbb{R}^2 \text{ using basis } v'
\end{CD}

Comment: This shortcut is how the matrix of a linear transformation, in a basis, is quite commonly defined, while the observation that the matrix transforms according to $PAP^{-1}$ is given as a consequence. I suppose one could reverse the roles, but I don't remember any author doing that.

Comment: @user85667 I edited by adding some detail of my confusion, can you read again?

Comment: Maybe it is better to call $f$ the linear map which matrix is $A$ in the basis $v$. The matrix $[f]_{v'}^{v'}=A'$ is obtained by computing $f(v')$ in the basis $v'$, but note that the expressions that you have for $v'$ are their coordinates in the basis $v$. If you want we can say that $v'=[v']_v$. So, you don't compute $f(v')$ my multiplying the unknown matrix $A'$ by the $v'$ that you have,

Comment: To compute $f$ on a vector written in coordinates in $v$, we use $A$. So, $[f(v')]_v=[f]_v[v']_v=Av'$. Then, since you need $[f(v')]_v'$ you write $Av'$ in the basis $v'$ to get $[Av']_{v'}$.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe reading 《linear algebra done right》chapter3 is helpful. In this problem, linear transformation is known. Matrix is a way to show it. To finding its matrix under bases $v_{1}^{\prime}, v_{2}^{\prime}$,the only thing we need is how this transformation affect on bases $v_{1}^{\prime}, v_{2}^{\prime}$.Solve $Av_{1}^{\prime}, Av_{2}^{\prime}$ and rewrite them as a linear combination of $v_{1}^{\prime}, v_{2}^{\prime}$,then the column of matrix solved because of matrix definition.

Answer (score 0):

1. A linear map is completely determined by its action on a basis.
2. $M e_i$ is the $i$th column of the matrix $M$.
3. $P=[I]^e_{v'}$ by definition is the matrix such that $e_i=Pv_i‘$
4. $Av'_i$ can be written in the basis as $\alpha_{i1}v'_1+\alpha_{i2}v'_2$
5. from $A'=PAP^{-1}$ we get  \begin{align}A'e_i &\overset5= PAP^{-1} e_i \\&\overset3= PAv'_i\\&\overset4= P(\alpha_{i1}v'_1+\alpha_{i2}v'_2)\\&\overset{\llap{\text{linearity}}}=\alpha_{i1}Pv'_1+\alpha_{i2}Pv'_2\\ &\overset3=\alpha_{i1}e_1+\alpha_{i2}e_2 = \binom{\alpha_{i1}}{\alpha_{i2}}.\end{align}
   In this way we see that $A'=\begin{pmatrix}\alpha_{11}& \alpha_{12} \\ \alpha_{11}& \alpha_{12} \end{pmatrix}$, the matrix of coefficients.